# How to disable LinkButton within GridViewclick from Client Side using JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView, In one column I have LinkButton control. I want to disable click from client side for certain condition on this column. Means for some rows it will not be possible for User to call onclick event and for some rows it is possible. 
I want to achieve this from client side using javascript. 
Or When User clicks on link, It will notify the User that this action can't be completed for this row.

```
<asp:GridView Width="100%" ShowHeader="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled" GridLines="Both" CellPadding="10" CellSpacing="5" ID="GridViewMultiplePOSAssociationId" runat="server" AllowSorting="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="RewardGridMultiD_RowCommand"
AllowPaging="true" PageSize="8" OnRowDataBound="grdViewCustomers_OnRowDataBound" PagerSettings-Position="Top" PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" PagerSettings-FirstPageText="First" PagerSettings-LastPageText="Last" DataKeyNames="POS Id">
    <RowStyle CssClass="table_inner_text" BackColor="WhiteSmoke" BorderColor="CornflowerBlue" Wrap="true" ForeColor="Black" Height="30px" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="table_head_text" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="80px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval(" POS Id ") %>');">
                    <img alt="Details" id="imgdiv<%# Eval("POS Id") %>" src="images/plus.png" />
                </a>
                <div id="div<%# Eval(" POS Id ") %>" style="display: none;">
                    <asp:GridView ID="grdViewOrdersOfCustomer" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="ChildGrid">
                        <RowStyle CssClass="table_inner_text" BackColor="SkyBlue" BorderColor="Black" Wrap="true" ForeColor="White" Height="30px" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="RULE FILE NAME" HeaderText="RULE FILE NAME" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="RULE ID" HeaderText="RULE ID" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="RULE TYPE ID" HeaderText="RULE TYPE ID" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="START TIME" HeaderText="START TIME" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="EXPIRY TIME" HeaderText="EXPIRY TIME" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Row Number">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelRowNumberId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Row Number") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="POS Id">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelPOSID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("POS Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                <%-- <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkbtnPOSId" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("POS Id") %>' CommandName="ClickPOS" Text='<%#Eval("POS Id") %>' runat="server" CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>--%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-Width="250px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Action">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLinkAssociate" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("POS Id") %>' CommandName="Associate" Text="Associate" runat="server" OnClientClick="return OnClientClickAssociateRewardRuleFile(this);" CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>/
                <asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLinkReplace" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("POS Id") %>' CommandName="Replace" Text="Replace" runat="server" OnClientClick="return OnClientClickReplaceRewardRuleFile(this);" CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-Width="250px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LabelStatusPendingPOSId" Text='<%#Eval("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In GridViewMultiplePOSAssociationId there is one column "Status" which has label LabelStatusPendingPOSId, LabelStatusPendingPOSId text is set Applied, Not Applied at the time of Binding. For Rows which has Status Applied, User should not be able to click on LinkButton Associate/Replace else He is allowed to click.

Answer (score 0):

use this code `OnRowDataBound` for Your Grid

```
 protected void grdViewCustomers_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    { 
        if (e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
    LinkButton LinkbtnPOSId=(LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkbtnPOSId");
    Label LabelStatusPendingPOSId = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("LabelStatusPendingPOSId");
    Boolean boolStatus = LabelStatusPendingPOSId.Text == "Applied" ? true : false;
    //LinkbtnPOSId.Attributes.Add("onclick", "function CheckStatus('" + boolStatus.ToString() + "')");   
    LinkbtnPOSId.Enabled = boolStatus;

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

You can loop through the `Gridview` and make the particular control disable...

I am writing the code in javascript pageload function...

```
function PageLoad(sender, args) 
{
    for (var i = 0; i <= RowCount; i++) 
    {
        document.getElementById('Gridview1_HyperLinkAssociate_' + i.toString() + '').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Set `RowCount` as the number of rows of the Gridview...